# How to match $ or $$ but not if they are either of these <$ and <$$

Tags: regex

I want to match `$` or `$$` in a string
but not if they have a `<` in front of them

this seems close but it is matching a single `$` in the `<$$` case

```
(?<!\<)\$\$|(?<!\<)\$
```

so...

`$BS<$BI>` - matches BS

`$$BS<$$BI>` - matches BS

Comment: `<$$` will match the second `$` because it doesn't have `<` in front of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex with 2 negative lookbehind assertions:

```
(?<!<)(?<!<\$)\$\$?
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/G2C9Ma/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?<!<)`: Assert that we don't have `<` at previous position
- `(?<!<\$)`: Assert that we don't have `<$` at previous position
- `\$\$?`: Match 1 or 2 `$` characters

Comment: that's great! I was looking at this for ages!

Comment: Just fyi that `(?<!<)(?<!<\$)\${1,2}` can also be used.

Answer (score 0):

You could also consume what you don't want and then match what you do want in an alternation.

```
/\<\$\$?(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\$\$?/g
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is using a match for what you don't want and an alternation with a capturing group to keep what you do want:

```
<\${1,2}|(\${1,2})
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jZwA8t/1)

If a quantifier in the lookbehind is supported you could use:

```
(?<!<\$?)\${1,2}
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/N9QdB2/1)